# Getting the dimensions of a newly updated image element

Tags: javascript, dhtml

I'm having an issue with getting the dimensions of a newly updated image element.

I'm using FileReader to display a preview of an image file on screen.
Once the filereader and associated code has finished executing, I retrieve the new dimensions of the image element so I can adjust them accordingly.

On some browsers, the info doesn't get updated straight away and I need to include a delay before I can retrieve the new dimensions.  This results in the new image being resized according to the previous image's dimensions, and not its own.

**How can I be sure the new image has been fully loaded?**

I would have thought `FileReader().onloadend` would have been sufficient but apparently not.  I think this is executed once the fileReader has loaded it, not when the DOM has rendered it. (Am I right?)

Then I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399508/dhtml-get-updated-element-size), which suggests using a timeout of 1 millisecond.  This works sometimes, but not always.  It seems to be down to the speed the browser is rendering the image (more-so available resources rather than filesize).  Do we have no other way of detecting a change in these parameters?

HTML

```
<img src="#.png" alt=""/>
<input id="fileInput" type="file" accept='image/*' onChange="loadIt()" />
```

JS

```
preview = getElementsByTagName('img')[0];

function loadIt() {

    var imgReader = new FileReader();
    imgReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById('fileInput').files[0]); //read from file input

    imgReader.onloadstart = function(e) {
        //
    }
    imgReader.onload = function (imgReaderEvent) {
        if (isImage()) {
            preview.src = imgReaderEvent.target.result;
            //
        }
        else {
            preview.src = 'error.png';
            //
        }
    }
    imgReader.onloadend = function(e) {

        setImage();

        setTimeout(function(){
            setImage();
        }, 1);

        setTimeout(function(){
            setImage();
        }, 2000);
        //
    }
};

function setImage() {
    preview_w = preview.width;
    preview_h = preview.height;
    console.log('dimensions: '+avatar_preview_w+' x '+avatar_preview_h);
    //
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `preview.onload` or `preview.onloadend` on your image to detect that it has finished loading. You're also calling your events after you `readAsDataURL` The code should look like this

```
var preview=document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
function loadIt() {
   var imgReader=new FileReader();
   imgReader.onload=function(){
   if (isImage()) {
      preview.src = imgReader.result;
      preview.onload=setImage;
   } else {
      preview.src = 'error.png';
      //
   }
   imgReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById('fileInput').files[0]); //read from file input
}
function setImage(){
   preview_w = preview.width;
   preview_h = preview.height;
   console.log('dimensions: '+avatar_preview_w+' x '+avatar_preview_h);
}
```

Comment: Changed my code to have `readAsDataURL` executed after onload. Don't see any chaange. Adding `preview.onload=setImage;` after setting src didn't help at all.

Comment: MY BAD: `preview.onload=setImage;` did work.  I was using `preview.onload=setImage();` which, although worked did not have updated values. why is this?

Comment: @patrick it is executing right when you say `preview.onload=setImage();` because of the open and close parenthesis. That is why.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling  `imgReader.readAsDataURL` before your `.onload` and `.onloadend` is set.

I do not know what some of the variables are with-in the body of your `setImage()`;however, start here:

```
function loadIt() {

    var preview = getElementsByTagName('img')[0],

        setImage = function () {
        preview_w = preview.width;
        preview_h = preview.height;
        console.log('dimensions: '+avatar_preview_w+' x '+avatar_preview_h);
    },

    imgReader = new FileReader();

    imgReader.onloadstart = function(e) {};

    imgReader.onload = function (imgReaderEvent) {
        if (isImage()) {
            preview.src = imgReaderEvent.target.result;
        }
        else {
            preview.src = 'error.png';
        };
    };

    imgReader.onloadend = function(e) {setImage();};

    imgReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById('fileInput').files[0]); //read from file input
};
```

Comment: What variables in setImage()? You havn't addressed anything re detecting that image has finished loading

Comment: You should not have to re-detect if the image is loaded because you're already detecting if image is loaded by attached a function to the .onloadend and .onload, and .onloadstart. There are some variables that are unaccounted for because the poster did not share them with us and or unless they're some type of global variable. I'm only addressing the question.

Comment: isImage() is a custom function that returns true if the file extension is .png, .jpg, etc.  Also, .onloadend is executed when the image has been loaded by the FileReader, not by the DOM